# Batch Script - FINDSTR End Result?

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

I have a backup script that outputs

`Backup %DIRNAME% %TIME% >>Results.txt`
This looks like :

Backup B:\Backup\Documents 92

now later I was wondering how I'd present only the output from time taken to complete

I tried
`FINDSTR /r "^[1-9][0-9]*$ ^0$" results.txt`

But that does nothing
I know this works because if I make a rand.txt with rand num the findstr outputs what's in that file.
Maybe there's a one for last entry in file

like `FINDSTR "[1-9][0-9]\.$" results.txt`

-
Later figured in command prompt we can do

`FOR /F "eol=; tokens=3* delims=, " %i in (results.txt) do @echo %j %k`

Can actually be as simple as

`FOR /F " tokens=3* delims=, " %I in (results.txt) do @echo %I>timeresult`

`type timeresult`

This also means we can concatenate random results to .txt but results we want to pull remember not to put , at the start.

Still formatting this for batch ?

Also a new question arises, how to put this in a variable ?

My guess was

`FOR /F "eol=; tokens=3* delims=, " %i in (results.txt) do ( set result= %j %k`

---

Answered:
Yeah, answered my own question...
Don't know why I was trying to over complicate things.

So this grabs token 3 sets var T for Time in results and then makes usable Variable later

FOR /F "tokens=3" %%T in (results.txt) do ( set vartmp=%%T )

Amazing what happens when you walk away, grab a coffee and do some thing else lol. You're like why.. didn't I just type that.

Thank you for peoples comments, was great to see other people's ideas and input, appreciated.

Comment: First thing to do would be to clarify what you mean by "only the output from time". Perhaps if you'd say what format you use for `%time%` and what you wanted to produce we'd be better able to assist.

Comment: The output from Backup 2 is

Backup B:\Backups\documents 92seconds

That's an output from a different script

Then I was wanting to do a 

for in ('FINDSTR /r "^[1-9][0-9]*$ ^0$" results.txt') do ( set result=%%VAR? )

then that leads to another one I haven't figured out yet. ~Setting the string found into a variable so I could use
echo Time Taken On Last Documents Backup %bkResultTime%

Answer (score 0):

This will give the last set of numbers on the line

```
type Results.txt|repl "^.* (\d+).*$" "$1" >newfile.txt
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

**Edited according to comments:**

Comment: I liked the effort of repl.bat but unfortunately it returns the same data as in results.txt

Comment: I notice your reply comment has `92seconds` and there is no way you got that from `%time%` unless you misused the time variable name.  The format of the time in your files needs to be known, with spaces etc too.

Comment: My Bad, sorry %time% is the time taken to complete that's obviously changed now to %timetakentocomple% & actual time is %date% with time concatenated with it. I figured out from the new for example I wanted to try that I can just do FOR /F "tokens=2,3* delims=, " %i in (results.txt) do @echo %j %k but how do I put this and the var to work in a batch (updated original question)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q21446192.txt) DO CALL :lastnum %%a

GOTO :EOF

:lastnum
SET "elapsed=%~2"
IF DEFINED elapsed shift&GOTO lastnum
SET "elapsed=%~1"
SET /a total=0
:numlp
FOR /l %%n IN (0,1,9) DO IF "%elapsed:~0,1%"=="%%n" SET /a total=%%n+10*total&SET elapsed=%elapsed:~1%&GOTO numlp
if "%elapsed%"=="%~1" GOTO :eof
ECHO %total%
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q21446192.txt` for my testing which contained the one data item you've given us. It produced `92`

`%time%` is a magic variable. `CMD` will set it to the current time in user's format, but will be overridden by a user-set variable. It's assumed to be the default on SO.